# How to set the value of textbox in vba access form to query field value

Tags: vba, ms-access

[The form I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Kyq.png)

How do I set the value of the textbox status to the field value of a query. After the selecting the value of the comboxbox, the textbox should show a field value of the query based on the selected product_code from the combobox. combo box uses another table to but product-code is the same in both data sources

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, edit your question to include your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use *DLookup*:

```
=DLookup("[FieldName]","[QueryName]","[ProductCode] = " & [cboProductCode] & "")
```

If the code is text:

```
=DLookup("[FieldName]","[QueryName]","[ProductCode] = '" & [cboProductCode] & "'")
```

Comment: I tried to paste it defaultvalue setting but it keeps erasing after complaining of invalid syntax error

Comment: Default values only display on a new record.

Comment: i dont get what yo meant with this. Why is it showing syntax error? ofcourse <i have found another way to solve the problem but i would like to use your solution because it is more elegant

Comment: You could append your current solution to your question as well as your attempt for another solution.